# Executing arbitrary code with cat command when reading access.log

Tags: apache

I made this file based on a combination of hexadecimal that can break`cat` and the terminal showing the file with `cat`, and the reset command does not work anymore:

[Download Cat Killer Version 1](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=92314620383274317188)

To test, download the script file and execute `cat brokecat` on it and you will see.

Another example is executing `cat /usr/bin/vi` that can execute some arbitrary, but not valid commands on terminal.

I am now trying to do the same thing on my Apache server by including some of these characters in the URI. I imagine that if someone opens the access logs using `cat` that this executes some arbitrary commands on the server using the same logic.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am trying to make access.log to execute some arbitrary commands, when i run cat /var/log/apache2/access.log, i am trying to understand if that is possible.  Because cat command sometimes reacts bad to some binary codes in file, imagine that the user types something in the URI with this binary codes and this goes to my access.log (obviously), when i reading my /var/log/apache2/access.log, something bad can gonna happen. Do you understand?

Comment: ok - I tried to narrow in on your question - I hope my edits are what you intended to say

Comment: there is a small problem with your question - if it *is* possible, then that would be a major bug in `cat` and should remain private and disclosed to the developers who can release a patch before your disclosure to the world

Comment: no need to delete the question, just that you might not get the detailed answers you hope for

Comment: There is a inotify that you can setup to monitor the log files, but you would have to program it.  http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

Comment: No i dont hope any detailed answers...

Comment: You're not breaking `cat` at all; `cat killer >/dev/null` or `cat killer | awk 0` will work fine all day long. When you output _to a terminal window with any program_, `cat dd tr` or even `gzip|gunzip`, it _may_ break the _terminal window_ depending on what terminal program and perhaps options you use but didn't hint at. If outputting garbage to your terminal is an issue, use a program or option that checks for garbage before outputting it, such as the very convenient `less` or `cat -v`.